# Laravel installed on a local volume (Mac) from docker nginx/php-fpm can't write session files

Tags: php, laravel, session, permissions, docker

I have a docker-compose.yml file that runs the following (create image called mmm/nginx):

```
web:
 image: mmm/nginx
 ports:
 - "80:80"
 volumes:
 - ./var:/var/www
 - ./etc/nginx/sites-enabled:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
 links:
 - php
 - db

php:
 image: rossriley/php56-fpm
 volumes:
 - ./var:/var/www
 - ./etc/php5/php-fpm.conf:/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf
 links:
 - db

db:
 image: sameersbn/mysql
 ports:
 - "3306:3306"
 volumes:
 - /var/lib/mysql
 environment:
 - DB_NAME=tables
 - DB_USER=table
 - DB_PASS=pass
```

it serves up the websites nicely that are stored in `/var/www`

The issue happens when it tries to write to the logs and tries to write session files. While **it does** create the files, it can't write them.

The folder for the `storage` and its nested directories have the permissions set to `777`.

In order for laravel to write to them, I have to `$ chmod 777 <.log|sessionfile>` and it works nicely. Clearly, this is not the way to develop as I need to start new sessions regularly and create new logs daily.

How can I give laravel and the docker containers permission to write the files they create?

**Update:**
This is what laravel's log says:

```
local.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'file_put_contents(/var/www/com.mtrinteractive.sandbox.form/storage/framework/sessions/e0117b8ca17af9c19572ddb305a272b4c22bd18d): failed to open stream: Permission denied' in /var/www/com.mtrinteractive.sandbox.form/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:81
```

**Update #2**

Here's the project directory:

[image]

**Update #3**

Here are the project's permissions and owners:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to $ chmod 777 the storage directory and the public directory.

Comment: I did, and it allowed the creation of files in there, but then it couldn't write it.

Comment: Try `chmod -R gu+w www ` OR `chmod -R o+w storage`

Comment: Just tried that now and nothing. :/

Comment: `sudo chmod -R 770 /your/path/to/laravel/folder/`   and `sudo chgrp -R www-data /your/path/to/laravel/folder/`

Comment: oh wait, I didn't see the `chmod -R o+w storage` cmd, let me try that one real quick.

Comment: for the `sudo chmod -R...` do I chmod the root folder or just the storage folder?

Comment: storage and public folders are the one you need to own to write any file.

Comment: But you can do it to the laravel folder.

Comment: no such group: `www-data`

Comment: One last try: `chmod -R 755 laravelfolder` try with and without sudo

Comment: Are you using vagrant ?

Comment: Also, do you have the folder: `storage/framework/sessions` ?

Comment: Just wanna thank you for taking the time here  to help me out. And no, I'm using docker. It creates the session files and log files but can't write to them for some reason. If I chmod the entire directory, it registers it in git as a change too.

Comment: If you don't have the folder `storage/framework/sessions` can you create one and try again?

Comment: If that didn't help, try: `php artisan cache:clear` from the project directory, then `chmod -R 777 app/storage` and finally `php artisan dump-autoload`

Comment: I did the all up to the `php artisan dump-autoload` and got `  [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]  
  Command "dump-autoload" is not defined.  `

Comment: Try `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: the dump worked, but Laravel is still unable to write to the files it creates. do you know how to find out what group laravel and docker containers are under on the mac?

Comment: Nope, I wouldn't know. :(

Comment: I'll manually `chmod` them for now. I'll post any updates later if I find a solution for this.

Comment: That's good. Let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this help, but if your using a Dockerfile you can add

RUN usermod -u 1000 nginx

or if your using Apache you can sub. nginx for apache.

This seems to be only an issue for OS X and the issue is actually something to do with VirtualBox and not directly related to Docker. I had this issue with Docker v1.9.x and now again with v1.10.3. This time I was not able to solve it with the above solution but was able to solve it by writing my cache to a database. In this case it was MySQL/MariaDB but could have easily been memcache or redis.

Oddly, creation of log files and writing to them wasn't an issue even though the volume is mounted a separately but originated in the same folder '/Users' of my Mac.