# On mac OS X terminal, how to see what user created file

Tags: php, macos, shell, command-line

I would like to see what user creates my log files for my php project. Strangely enough, PHP can create the files but it can't write to them so I have `chmod` them all the time. I would like to see what user is creating them and grant that user permission to write to the files in the folder as well.

`echo exec('whoami');` currently returns `www-data` but I have no such user, just `_www`. I should note that I'm running it on docker from a v-machine.

Is there a terminal command that lets me see who created a specific file? Thanks.

Comment: `ls -l filename` will show the owner of the file.

Comment: Owner is the same as creator?

Comment: The reason I'm asking is because php can create it but then  complains that it can't write to it.

Comment: When a file is created, its owner is set to the creator. The owner can be changed afterward, but only root can do that.

Comment: If you have to `chmod` them, that means the ownership isn't the problem, the permissions are. It sounds like the file is being created without write permissions for the owner. Show the code that creates the file.

Comment: It's Laravel's file session handler. I already opened up a question that details that issue. I'll post a link to it shortly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35302635/laravel-installed-on-a-local-volume-mac-from-docker-nginx-php-fpm-cant-write?noredirect=1#comment58317536_35302635

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can try with `stat`. For example:

```
$ touch file
$ stat file
File: `file'
Size: 0             Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 801h/2049d  Inode: 18874836    Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: (  500/   mauro)   Gid: (  500/   mauro)
Access: 2016-02-10 13:37:13.678996997 -0500
Modify: 2016-02-10 13:37:13.678996997 -0500
Change: 2016-02-10 13:37:13.678996997 -0500
```

Or just:

```
$ stat --format=%U file
mauro
```

Comment: `stat --format=%U file` now returns `stat: illegal option -- -` on macOS BigSur

Answer (score 4):

Stat should be able to help with that. Try the following:

```
stat -f "%Su" file_path
```