# Deleting quarantine files: xattr error in Mac terminal

Tags: terminal, command-line

I'm trying the following command to delete quarantined files:

```
sudo xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine mydirectory
```

I get the error:

```
attr: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted:
```

I have full permission to the folder, and I've disabled SIP on Mac. On the actual files within this directory, my permission is "custom access" and that doesn't seem to be able to be modified.

Running `ls -lO` I don't see any permissions issue on the files in the directory.

What else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

As described in [this article](https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2012/11/20/clearing-the-quarantine-extended-attribute-from-downloaded-applications/) from [Rich Trouton](https://derflounder.wordpress.com/about-2/), check if your files have that extended attribute:

```bash
cd /path/to/mydirectory
find . -xattrname com.apple.quarantine
```

You can try and limit your `xattr -d` to only those files.

```bash
cd /path/to/mydirectory
find . -xattrname com.apple.quarantine -exec  xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine {} \;
```

But if it is still not working, [check the ownership of your folder and its content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35323245/6309). And their ACLs (`ls -le`).
Check also their [immutable flag (`ls -lO`)](https://superuser.com/q/1246801/141).